# What does "pointer to register variable" as function parameter do?

Tags: c, function, calling-convention, function-declaration, register-keyword

As I understand, `register` specifier hints the compiler to store the variable in a register. This was all fine until I came across the following declaration in `XKBlib.h` from Xorg-7.7:

```
extern  int     XkbTranslateKeySym(
    Display *           /* dpy */,
    register KeySym *       /* sym_return */,
    unsigned int        /* modifiers */,
    char *          /* buffer */,
    int             /* nbytes */,
    int *           /* extra_rtrn */
);
```

Note how `sym_return` is passed as a *pointer to register variable*. What makes me wonder is that

1. this seems allowed, despite the impossibility of taking address of a register variable,
2. this seems to somehow be important to be mentioned in a function declaration.

Point 1. appears to be somehow invalid, because I appear to be able to pass a pointer to a non-`register` variable, even with `-pedantic-errors` flag for GCC.

So, what does this declaration change compared to the one with omitted `register` keyword? Does it alter calling convention or what?

Comment: `register` is a storage class specifier like `extern`, not a cv-qualifier (const/volatile). `register` here applies to `KeySym*`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `register` keyword is mostly an obsolete feature in modern C. It does two things:

- Tell the compiler that it should try to store the variable in a CPU register if possible. The compiler is nowadays much more suited to make such calls than the programmer, hence obsolete feature.
- Blocks the programmer from taking the address of the variable.

In your case, it says that the pointer *itself*, not the pointed-at data, should preferably be stored in a register, presumably an address/index register. From a standard C view it doesn't do anything else than that.

It may be that a certain exotic compiler picks a certain calling convention when given `register` as part of the function, although I have never seen that before. Praxis for calling convention is rather something along the lines of: "if parameter n is a pointer, store it in index register x, if parameter n+1 is a pointer, store it index register y" and the like.

I would suspect that the most likely explanation for the `register` keyword here is that the programmer didn't know what they were doing. Particularly since no comment about it was left in the header - that's a fairly certain indication of incompetence. Looking at the header as whole, there's lots of other signs supporting the incompetence theory, such as this blatant bug: `#define XkbLC_BeepOnComposeFail (1<<31)`. When you can find UB within a few minutes of briefly reviewing the source, stay clear of it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not taking the address of register variable, i.e. it is not a pointer to register variable. Rather it is hinting that the pointer itself (remember, pointers are just variable) should be placed in a register.

Comment: So, does it thereby alter calling convention?

Comment: @Ruslan what do you mean by "alter calling convention"?

Comment: I mean that normally, on i386 SysV ABI, function parameters are passed via stack. If one parameter is `register`, then it shouldn't as it seems, which then would violate the ABI (unless it's explicitly mentioned there, which I didn't think to check).

Comment: Got your question, but sorry, I don't know the answer of that :-(